# Is there any way to use / induce the camera of a cell phone to read QR Code without making use of any app, in Android?

Tags: android, mobile

For example, I just point my cell phone to a QR Code and the information read is (optionally) stored.

Comment: You are welcome to see if there is a library that you can embed in your app for QR code scanning. For example, you could search `android qr code scan library` in your favorite search engine. Or, you could look in [the "QR Codes" category on the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/81?sort=created).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the prompt reply, but my question is if there is any way to read a qr code without using any app, plugin or library. Make reading with only the cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is if there is any way to read a qr code without using any app, plugin or library

No.